# Is it possible to create a react native project on a hard drive other than the c: drive?

Tags: javascript, react-native, android-studio, sdk

Can anybody help me.

I have two drives, one is a 128gb SSD but I only use that for the system and important things. And I have another 1tb hard drive.

I installed all the necessary react native tools on my hard drive. But when I try to create a react native project on my hard drive it fails, I get an error saying I need the SDK.

But if I create the project on my SSD it is created but I never installed anything from the SDK or JDK or android studio there. And the problem is that all the react native projects take me at least 2gb so I'm running out of space on the SSD.

Does anyone know why I can't create a project on my hard drive?

As I said, I already tried to completely uninstall android studio and all its tools and reinstall them on my hard drive to see if I could create the projects inside it. But it does not work